# Tikz: How can I produce a curved line like this?

Tags: tikz-styles

p1 and p2 are points given by their x and y coordinates.
The line must have this left to right direction.

I have no idea how I can do this, I tried using 
something like

`\draw [dashed] plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (-5,0) (-4, 1) (-3,3)};`

But it doesn't work for my purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (5,4);
   \draw [dashed,thick] (A) to[out=90,in=180] (B);
   \fill (A) circle [radius=1pt] (B) circle [radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Actually you can use the coordinates directly instead of specifying them first with `\coordinate`. The `in` and `out` options take an angle as value.